# не работает шаблон Navigation Drawer Activity

Tags: activity

Обновил Android Studio, в месте с ним обновился шаблон Navigation Drawer Activity.При выборе по пункта меню,с помощью клавиатуры происходит смена  фрагментов, но при использовании мыши или пальца ничего не происходит.Как это исправить?

Comment: Android studio 3.5

Comment: Удалось решить проблему? Сегодня тоже столкнулся с этим...

Comment: Сегодня обновился и заработало:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В техподдержке ответили "...Based on some experiments, this seems to be a problem with upgrading from Android Studio 3.4 to 3.5... which was resolved in Android Studio 3.5.1. It has to do with the NavigationHostFragment and the drawer being generated in the wrong order in the XML.

После обновления Android Studio до 3.5.1 создайте новый Navigation Drawer Activity и всё будет работать как и должно.

Answer (score 1):

В версии 4.0.1 до сих пор не поправили!
нужно поменять местами

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView/>
```

и

```
<include/>
```

Comment: Помогло, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Сегодня столкнулся с такой-же проблемой, но на Android 3.6.3.
Как выяснилось проблема была в том, что шаблон не корректно создавал main_activity.xml
В ней не в том порядке стояли элементы. После того как я перекинул NavigationView в самый конец DrawerLayout все заработало.